# File path not recognised in winforms resource (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, wmv

I have a windows media player tool that I want to play a local video when my app opens. The video is stored in resources and set to copy always (I am not sure if this is correct as I have been doing this for local HTML pages and I just assumed that its the same with video files as well.) and has been added to the solution.

I have been using the syntax: `"file:///{0}/mail/index.html"` for HTML pages, but I'm not sure if this is to be used for media as well.

the code I have for the video player/file:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "file:///{0}/Resources/newintrovid.wmv";
}
```

The problem is it's not recognising `"file:///{0}Resources/newintrovid.wmv"` as a path, am I doing something really stupid here? I've followed the instructions on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383953(v=vs.90).aspx) and I keep coming up with a 'cannot find file' error in the solution.

As an extra note, I want the media player and video to close when the video is finished. I've had a look online but I can't find any method to this. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is a difference between Web Application Paths and WIndows application File Paths.. in windows application where is the `.wmv` file located..? do a google search on Resource files or how to use `File.Path`

Comment: well, I can pretty much guarantee that {0} is not part of the actual file path. Did you miss a `string.format()` around that string, with some value to put in the placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely you are missing a call to `string.Format` around your string, with a variable to fill in the `{0}` placeholder.

Something like this should work (obviously you should substitute the real paths for your application):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mediaPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office";

    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = 
        string.Format("file:///{0}/root/fre/StartMenu_Win7.wmv", mediaPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go. on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383953(v=vs.90).aspx) it seemed a whole lot simpler but the instructions were pretty vague.